# Trouble about getting info from DB using c# combobox

Tags: c#, sql, database

```
private void datatimeDateEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DateTimevar = datatimeDateEdit.SelectedText.ToString();
    this.testtabTableAdapter.Fill(this.testdb1DataSet.testtab["DataTime"]=DateTimevar);
}
```

The error looks like

> cannot convert from string to int

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: what is the type of Datetime in your db?

Comment: Is the type of "DataTime" int?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void datatimeDateEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.testtabTableAdapter.Fill(this.testdb1DataSet.testtab["DataTime"]=
                 Convert.ToDateTime(datatimeDateEdit.SelectedText));
}
```

Comment: Still same prob, VS2015 underline this ["DataTime"]